# Update query on PostgreSQL table not working

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I am trying to build a PostgreSQL database with Python code that will simulate a tournament. The players table contains four columns - name, id, wins, matches.

The `reportMatch()` function takes in two arguments, the ids of the winner and the loser of a particular match and updates the statistics in the database. It will increment the "wins" of the winner by 1, and the "matches" of both the players by 1.

```
def reportMatch(winner, loser):
    conn = connect()
    c = conn.cursor()
    SQL = 'update players set wins = 1 where id = %s;'
    data = (winner, )
    c.execute(SQL, data)
    SQL = 'update players set matches = 1 where id = %s or id = %s;'
    data = (winner, loser)
    c.execute(SQL, data)
```

I know I shouldn't set the wins and matches to 1, since it's not incrementing the current value, but the database currently has no matches. So, the first time I run it, setting the value to 1 works temporarily.

The above function is called through a client code function, `testReportMatches()`:

```
def testReportMatches():
    registerPlayer("Bruno Walton")
    registerPlayer("Boots O'Neal")
    registerPlayer("Cathy Burton")
    registerPlayer("Diane Grant")
    standings = playerStandings()
    [id1, id2, id3, id4] = [row[1] for row in standings]
    reportMatch(id1, id2)
    reportMatch(id3, id4)
    standings = playerStandings()
    for (n, i, w, m) in standings:
        if m != 1:
            raise ValueError("Each player should have one match recorded.")
        if i in (id1, id3) and w != 1:
            raise ValueError("Each match winner should have one win recorded.")
        elif i in (id2, id4) and w != 0:
            raise ValueError("Each match loser should have zero wins recorded.")
    print "7. After a match, players have updated standings."
```

`registerPlayer()` is used to insert a new player into the players database. `playerStandings()` is used to get a list of tuples of all the players.

The problem that I am running into is the update query in `reportMatch()`, which doesn't seem to work. I tried printing out standings before and after the two calls to `reportMatch()` in `testReportMatches()`, but both of them have matches and wins as 0. Somehow, the matches and wins in the database are not being updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to commit transaction with [`conn.commit()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.commit) at the end of `reportMatch` function.

See [psycopg2 usage](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html).

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I was such an idiot that I left out the commit.